# Property [id] does not exist on this collection instance in laravel 5.5

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5

I am working on `purchaseOrder` and `purchaseOrderDetails` database table.

I am saving data to two tables from one form. Here is the appended row table for `purchaseOrderrDetails` items. Insert data is working fine.

But, now I need to update the tables `purchaseOrder` and `purchaseOrderDetails` at a time.

I am trying to get all `purchaseOrderDetails` data to my form which is using the appended row system. And, I am getting this error:

> Property [id] does not exist on this collection instance

What should be the right code please someone helps me? Here are my controller method and edit view bellow-

Purchase_OrderController.php

```
   //purchase order update form
public function update($id){
    $suppliers   = Supplier::all();
    $categories = Category::all();

   $purchaseorder_id = $id;
   $purchaseorder= Purchase_Order::where('id', '=', $purchaseorder_id)->get();

   $purchaseorder_details_id = Purchase_Order_Details::pluck('purchase_order_id');
   $purchaseorder_details = Purchase_Order_Details::where('purchase_order_id', '=', $id)->get();
   //$purchaseorder_details = Purchase_Order_Details::with('purchaseorder')->get();


  //dd($purchaseorder_details);

    return view('user/purchaseorder.edit')->with(['purchaseorder' => $purchaseorder, 'purchaseorder_details' => $purchaseorder_details, 'suppliers' => $suppliers, 'categories' => $categories]);
}
```

edit.blade.php

```
<tbody>
      <?php $item_row = 0; ?>
      @foreach($purchaseorder_details as $pur_detail)
       <tr id="item-row-{{ $item_row }}">
        <td class="text-center" style="vertical-align: middle;">
        <button type="button" onclick="$(\'#item-row-' + item_row + '\').remove();" title="Delete" class="btn btn-xs btn-danger"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></button>
        </td>
        <td>
        <input value="{{ $pur_detail->code }}" class="form-control typeahead" required="required" placeholder="Item Code" name="item[{{ $item_row }}][code]" type="text" id="item-name-{{ $item_row }}">
        </td>
        <td>
        <input value="{{ $pur_detail->item_name }}" class="form-control" required="required" name="item[{{ $item_row }}][item_name]" type="text" id="item-name-{{ $item_row }}">
        </td>
        <td>
        <select class="form-control" required="required" name="item[{{ $item_row }}][category]" id="item-category-{{ $item_row }}">
       <option selected="selected" value="">Select Category</option>
         @foreach($categories as $category)
          <option value="{{ $category->id }}">{{ $category->name }}</option>
         @endforeach
        </select>
        </td>
        <td>
        <input value="{{ $pur_detail->quantity }}" class="form-control text-right" required="required" name="item[{{ $item_row }}][quantity]" type="text" id="item-quantity-{{ $item_row }}">
        </td>
        <td>
        <input value="{{ $pur_detail->uom }}" class="form-control text-right" required="required" name="item[{{ $item_row }}][uom]" type="text" id="item-uom-{{ $item_row }}">
        </td>
       </tr>
      @endforeach
       <?php $item_row++; ?>
       <tr id="addItem">
         <td class="text-center"><button type="button" onclick="addItem();" title="Add" class="btn btn-xs btn-primary" data-original-title="Add"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i></button></td>
         <td class="text-right" colspan="5"></td>
        </tr>
       </tbody>
```

And first one is - purchaseOrder and second one is purchaseOrderDetails 
[image: purchaseOrder]

[image: purchaseOrderDetails]

Comment: side note, we have a `$loop` var that you have in `foreach` loops, no need to be doing your own counts

Comment: can you please add the actual error

Comment: ErrorException (E_ERROR)
Property [id] does not exist on this collection instance. (View: E:\xampp\htdocs\printingpress\resources\views\user\purchaseorder\edit.blade.php)

Comment: And in collection.php -     public function __get($key)
    {
        if (! in_array($key, static::$proxies)) {
            throw new Exception("Property [{$key}] does not exist on this collection instance.");
        }
 
        return new HigherOrderCollectionProxy($this, $key);
    }

Comment: the line number of the error or what line in the paste above the error is for would be helpful, dont you think?

Comment: Here is no line number in view 'edit.blade.php' but in collection.php is '1763'

Comment: anywho, you are trying to use a collection as a model, that is why, you will have to find out where

Comment: I just want to update my two tables at a time using single form and second table has append row for many item. What code should I write .. Two models are - Purchase_Order and Purchase_Order_Details, would you please tell me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A Collection is a fancy object wrapper around an array, that is all. A Collection is NOT the things it contains, which is the mistake you are making.

```
$array = [
    ['id' => 1, 'name' => 'bob'],
    ['id' => 2, 'name' => 'tom'],
    ...
];
```

You wouldn't do this because you know the indexes you want are not on the array but the arrays inside of it:

```
$array['id'];
// but you would do this:
$array[0]['id'];
```

But with a Collection which is just an object around an array, you are doing that exact thing:

```
$collection->id;
```

Collections contain items, you want the 'id' from one of those items not the Collection itself as the Collection has no property named 'id'.

```
$collection->first()->id;   // id from the first object

foreach ($collection as $item) {
    $item->id;
}

etc ...
```

Comment: if you want to access only the first object key so you can do it like below 
$product = Product::create($wc_product);
$product->all();  // if only want to access id then use ->first();
$product['id'];


https://laravel.com/docs/master/collections#method-keys